# Nginx docker config mounting

Tags: docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy

I want to create an Nginx reverse proxy container with SSL but I get this error:

```
Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: 
OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: error during 
container init: error mounting "/docker-compose/nginx/nginx.conf" to rootfs at 
"/etc/nginx/nginx.conf": mount /docker-compose/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf (via 
/proc/self/fd/6), flags: 0x5000: not a directory: unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory 
onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type
admin@linvdevdock1:/docker-compose/nginx$
```

This is the docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: nginx_container
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
       - ./openproject.crt:/root/ssl/openproject.crt
       - ./openproject.key:/root/ssl/openproject.key
       - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    networks:
     - proxy

networks:
 proxy:
   external: true
   name: proxy
```

I do not understand the error message.
What is the problem here, please?

Comment: problem is in nginx.conf. Do u have ./nginx.conf file in your directory: /docker-compose/nginx/?

Comment: Yes there is. I tried default.config before, but that didn't work either. It is interesting if I take out that line the container starts and it doesn't complain about crt and key files.

Comment: if your .conf file is correct and complete, it should work. In addition, if there is a file (./nginx.conf), pls use this (read only: ro on container side), it may be useful: './nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro'  Also, disabling .conf file from outside of the container may help u to use default one.

Comment: Thank you for helping me. Thee was a typo  in the name of the config file. Silly me!